# Xcode tableview search filter for duplicate entries

Tags: iphone, uitableview, search, xcode4

I have a tableview with some of the same words under different sectionheaders and a searchfield.
When you are searching you will get duplicate results, I would like to filter these duplicate words from my search results.

Any ideas how to do this?

Comment: You are deciding what is shown during search. Why do you add duplicates if you don't want them. I don't understand the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a snippet of code I use to do the exact thing. You need to compare a unique string from each object to identify the duplicate. I do it with "myObject.uniqueID" in this example. Create an array with no duplicates, then `[tableView reloadData];`

```
- (void) removeDuplicates{

NSMutableDictionary * d = [[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithCapacity:0] autorelease];
NSMutableArray * noDuplicatesArray = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:0] autorelease];

Object* myObject; // whatever your object is
NSString * key;
NSString * value;

for ( int i=0; i<[duplicatesArray count]; i++ ){

    myObject = [duplicatesArray  objectAtIndex:i];
    key = myObject.uniqueID; // whatever makes this object unique (like a stock number, or ID)
    value = [d objectForKey:key];

    if ( value == nil ){

        [d setObject:key forKey:key];
        [noDuplicatesArray addObject:deal];
    }
}
    // now your noDuplicatesArray will have only unique entries. 
    // reload your tableview using the noDuplicatesArray


}
```